# Combinatorics and Permutations Problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My name is Shaun and I go in 7th standard; I am 13 years old.

I recently found a permutation problem which I have been stuck on for a while now.

**Problem**: Five brother-sister pairs took part in *k* activities. No brother-sister pair participated in the same activity. Any two people who were not a brother-sister pair were together in exactly one activity. One of the people took part in only two activities. What is the **minimum** value of *k*?

---

**Calculations**:

1. I used the combinatoric formula: n! / (n-r)! * r! => 10! /2! x 8! = 10 x 9/2 = 45 pairs
2. I removed 5 pairs because sister-brother may not be in the same activity: 45 - 5 = 40 pairs
3. Each person can be with 8 people (excluding brother-sister and itself), and they mention that one of the people only took part in 2 activities. 8 - 2 = 6 activities remaining.
4. 40 - 6 = 34 pairs/activities (for each pair they were together in exactly one activity.)

My answer: 34

**Another calculation: **

1. I used the combinatoric formula: n! / (n-r)! * r! => 10! /2! x 8! = 10 x 9/2 = 45 pairs
2. I removed 5 pairs because sister-brother may not be in the same activity: 45 - 5 = 40 pairs
3. (Interpretation of Jaap's comment): Each person can be with 8 other people in exactly one activity (excluding brother-sister and itself). Therefore, in two activities, one person can have max 16 pairs.
4. Because one person can only attend two activities, we have: 16 pairs
5. 40 - 16 = 24 pairs/activities (for each pair they were together in exactly one activity.)

**Answer**: 24 activities

---

My answers seem to be a little off from what they say:

**Answer: 14 activities**

Comment: Presumably an activity can be done by more than 2 people at the same time. That allows the person who did only 2 activities to have a shared activity with each other person (except their sibling) exactly once.

Comment: In that case, if I take 40 - 16 (8*2) I still get 24 as a result...I am not sure how to remove another 10 from it to get 14.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, my bad, it is 40-14 because she can attend 2 of the total activities that she can take part (16). So, 40 - 14 = 26

Comment: However, they mention that that two people may only be together in one activity. Then, she can only be in max 8 pairs, of which she only is in two pairs. I might be wrong, or right. I am not sure.

Comment: An activity can be done with at most 5 people - one from each pair. (I don't know the answer by the way, just commenting on your steps.)

Comment: Reposted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568857/combinatorics-and-permutations-find-the-least-number-of-activities where I gave an answer