# Combinatorics and Permutations: Find the least number of activities...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My name is Shaun and I go in 7th standard; I am 13 years old.

I recently found a permutation problem which I have been stuck on for a while now.

**Problem:** Five brother-sister pairs took part in k activities. No brother-sister pair participated in the same activity. Any two people who were not a brother-sister pair were together in exactly one activity. One of the people took part in only two activities. What is the minimum value of k?

**Calculations:**

I used the combinatoric formula: n! / (n-r)! * r! => 10! /2! x 8! = 10 x 9/2 = 45 pairs

I removed 5 pairs because sister-brother may not be in the same activity: 45 - 5 = 40 pairs

Each person can be with 8 people (excluding brother-sister and itself), and they mention that one of the people only took part in 2 activities. 8 - 2 = 6 activities remaining.

40 - 6 = 34 pairs/activities (for each pair they were together in exactly one activity.)

My answer: 34

**Another calculation:**

I used the combinatoric formula: n! / (n-r)! * r! => 10! /2! x 8! = 10 x 9/2 = 45 pairs

I removed 5 pairs because sister-brother may not be in the same activity: 45 - 5 = 40 pairs

(Interpretation of @JaapScherphuis comment): Each person can be with 8 other people in exactly one activity (excluding brother-sister and itself). Therefore, in two activities, one person can have max 16 pairs.

Because one person can only attend two activities, we have: 16 pairs

40 - 16 = 24 pairs/activities (for each pair they were together in exactly one activity.)

**Answer: 24 activities**

My answers seem to be a little off from what they say:

**Answer: 14 activities**

(I recently asked this question, but I am sending this again so that maybe a new set of mathematicians can help me. Thank you for your understanding!)

Comment: I think your calculations so far are assuming that each activity can only be done by 2 people, whereas you could have more. In fact, you could (in theory) have up to 5 doing an activity - can you see why you can't have more than 5?

Answer (score 1):

$14$ looks reasonable to me.

*"One of the people took part in only two activities"* looks an important phrase, so lets suppose that that person is $A$ and their sibling is $a$. The two activities of $A$ need to be divided between the other pairs with five people in each of those two activities, perhaps like

```
ABCDE
Abcde
```

The others apart from $A$ and $a$ need to pair up (more than two of them together would break a condition) $4\times 3 =12$ ways. Then $a$ needs to participate with them as efficiently as possible to meet the conditions, for example as

```
Bca
Bd
Be
Cba
Cd
Ce
Db
Dc
Dea
Eb
Ec
Eda
```

You cannot do better than this and $2+12=14$ activities

In a worst case  you could make $a$ take part separately with the other $8$, with $2+12+8=22$ as the maximum possible meeting the conditions

Comment: I have not checked this, but it looks at first glance as if you must have an even number of activities in total